# Is there software to change 'е' to 'ё' in Russian text?

Tags: text-processing, language

Can anyone tell me if there is a downloadable software program that will change 'е' to 'ё' when appropriate for beginning readers? I found one called Орфо but the links were either outdated or didn't work.

Comment: I don't use them myself so can't comment on their relative merits, but you can start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ёфикатор). One word of caution though: this _cannot_ be done algorithmically with certainty; in some cases the use of e and ё depends on the context and the intended meaning, especially in poetry.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://russiangram.com

It adds stress marks and dots for Ё to any Russian text. You can remove the stress marks if you don't need them using simple search-and-replace.

As for 'downloadable', I could create a Windows executable for you for a charge.  Please contact me at sales@morpher.ru for details.